# css hover alternative (automatic)

Tags: css, hover, transition

My CSS has to change using a transition ,and till now i used `div:hover` for that.

The transition needs to be activated when you click another `div`, not when you hover over the `div` that has to move/change .

How can I do that ?

Thanks

Evert

Comment: You need JavaScript to do that; is that okay?

Comment: If the div that you click on isn't a parent of the div that you want to animate, you can't write a selector to match it. You have to use JavaScript to do that.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You cannot handle click events on dom elements with css, you will need to use javascript for this.

You can add a click event to the first div which is fired when you click it. Within the event you select the other div, and make the transition.

[Working Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/dEpzu/)

You can do this by adding a class with the css transition:

**Html:**

```
<div id="clickme">1</div>
<div id="changeMe">2</div>
```

**Javascript:**

```
var el = document.getElementById('clickme');

el.onclick = function() {
    document.getElementById('changeMe').className = "transition";
};
```

**CSS:**

```
.transition{
   /* transition css */
}
```

Comment: This is a correct answer, but please provide a functional example for the OP.